# Unable to exit out of do-while loop?

Tags: c++

I can't figure out why the do-while loop isn't being terminated upon user entering -1 in input. Just ignore everything after the internal while loop. I know that the problem is somewhere in the while loop. I just don't see it.

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int input;
    std::string pass, company, timeS;
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter password length: ";
        std::cin >> input;
        while(input < 8 || input > 16)
        {
            if(!std::cin)
            {
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(100, '\n');
            }

            std::cout << "Password length must be between 8 and 16.\nEnter password length: ";
            std::cin >> input;
        }

        std::cout << "Enter company name: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, company);

        pass = passGen(input);
        time_t now = time(0);
        auto time = *std::localtime(&now);
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::put_time(&time, "%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S %a");
        timeS = ss.str();
        std::cout << "You passoword: " << pass << std::endl;
        writeFile(pass, company, timeS);

    }while(input != -1);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You ask for input in range `[8, 16]`. It will never be `-1` when it reaches the end of the outer loop.

Comment: Another issue is what happens if `std::cin.clear();` is NOT run after `std::cin >> input;`? What does `std::getline(std::cin, company);` see as the 1st character?

Answer (score 0):

The internal while loop will never terminate as the condition is will always be true for `-1`.

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int input;
    std::string pass, company, timeS;
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter password length: ";
        std::cin >> input;
        while((input < 8 && input>=0)|| input > 16)
        {
            if(!std::cin)
            {
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(100, '\n');
            }

            std::cout << "Password length must be between 8 and 16.\nEnter password length: ";
            std::cin >> input;
        }

        if (input>0){
          std::cout << "Enter company name: ";
          std::getline(std::cin, company);

          pass = passGen(input);
          time_t now = time(0);
          auto time = *std::localtime(&now);
          std::stringstream ss;
          ss << std::put_time(&time, "%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S %a");
          timeS = ss.str();
          std::cout << "You passoword: " << pass << std::endl;
          writeFile(pass, company, timeS);
        }
    }while(input != -1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make your answer complete by adding a full example please

Comment: This is the do-while implementation. Although this could be easily written using a just a while loop and if conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In this loop you wait for number between 8 and 16:

```
while(input < 8 || input > 16)
{
    if(!std::cin)
    {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    }

    std::cout << "Password length must be between 8 and 16.\nEnter password length: ";
    std::cin >> input;
}
```

Guess, what never comes out of that loop? Right, `-1` !! =)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will answer your question:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int input;
    std::string pass, company, timeS;
    // do
    // {
      while(true){
        std::cout << "Enter password length: ";
        std::cin >> input;
        if(input == -1){
          break;
        }
        while(input < 8 || input > 16)
        {
            if(!std::cin)
            {
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(100, '\n');
            }
            std::cout<< "=====>>>" << std::endl;

            std::cout << "Password length must be between 8 and 16.\nEnter password length: ";
            std::cin >> input;
        }
        std::cout << "Enter company name: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, company);

        pass = passGen(input);
        time_t now = time(0);
        auto time = *std::localtime(&now);
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::put_time(&time, "%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S %a");
        timeS = ss.str();
        std::cout << "You passoword: " << pass << std::endl;
        writeFile(pass, company, timeS);
      }
    // }while(input != -1);

  return 0;
}
```

Just use

```
while(true){
        //getting length of password  
        if(input == -1){
          break;
        }
        //rest of the logic
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just ignore everything after the internal while loop.

Ok. Let's do that...

```
int main()
{
    int input;
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter password length: ";
        std::cin >> input;
        while(input < 8 || input > 16)
        {
            std::cin >> input;
        }
    }while(input != -1);

    return 0;
}
```

> I know that the problem is somewhere in the while loop. I just don't see it.

I hope you see it now. Your inner while ensures that `input` is never `-1`.

I think your current problem is a symptom of not structuring your code. Hence, to fix your code I propose to use functions:

```
void do_something(int input);
bool read_and_validate(int& input) {
    input = 0;
    while(input < 8 || input > 16) {
        std::cin >> input;
        if (input == -1) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    int input;
    while( read_and_validate(input) ) {
        do_something(input);
    }    
}
```